# Azure Data Factory V1 - Date for Deprecation/End of life?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

In the Azure portal I get a message about that dataset and pipeline monitoring for Azure Data Factory V1 will be disabled on 2019-11-30. It seems to me that Azure Data Factory V1 is getting more and more deprecated and that one should migrate to Azure Data Factory V2 as soon as possible. Is there an approximate date for total deprecation or end of life set according to some roadmap?

Would be really appreciated to get an answer because if there's a near shutdown planned we need to assign resources to do this migration quickly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see any retirement notices here:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/?updatetype=retirements

However this announcement seems to have been made in the blog:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/

You can keep up to date with these announcements by subscribing to https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/feed/ in Outlook or another RSS compatible application.

You can subscribe to the retirement announcements here https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/feed/?product=data-factory&updatetype=retirements

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I've subscribed to the last mentioned RSS feed. However I'm unable to find any specific information about an exact or approximate date for end of life for ADF V1 anywhere in the sources you mention? Maybe you have insight to tell if we need to migrate within the nearest 6 months or less?

Comment: Unfortunately there doesn't seem to be any published roadmap.  There aren't any indications yet of a full end-of-life or deprecation of V1.  As a rule of thumb I would recommend that with every major version increment you/your business incorporate it in your service / software / product design lifecycle.

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE April 2021

In ["Migrate your Azure Data Factory version 1 to 2 service" update](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/migrate-your-azure-data-factory-version-1-to-2-service/), which was published on September 03, 2020, Azure announced that after 31 August 2023, Azure Data Factory version 1 will not be supported.

> With these enhanced functionalities, we are retiring Azure Data Factory version 1 on 31 August 2023. Please make the switch early to get the benefits of version 2 (current version).

> After 31 August 2023, Azure Data Factory version 1 will not be supported.